# Perl end-of-line parse discrepancy

Tags: perl, parsing, newline

TIA from a relative perl newbie.  I'm doing some parsing of input files, and running into an issue where the parsing is different on different linux boxes, and I have no idea why.   I'm parsing one line at a time, and trying to pick out a variable at the end of the line.  In one case the parse picks up the carriage return, in others it doesn't.

Starting with input file that looks like:

```
This is line one
This is line two
```

..such that each line has CR and LF at the end, thus the contents of the file is:

```
54 68 69 73 20 69 73 20 6C 69 6E 65 20 6F 6E 65 0D 0A
54 68 69 73 20 69 73 20 6C 69 6E 65 20 74 77 6F 0D 0A
```

When I run this code on the file:

```
open (INPUTFILEHANDLE, "<perlin.txt") || die "Could not open for read\n";
my $txtin = <INPUTFILEHANDLE>;
my $linelen = length($txtin);
($num) = ($txtin =~ /This is line (.*)/);
print "linelen: $linelen, num: $num\n";
my $txtin = <INPUTFILEHANDLE>;
my $linelen = length($txtin);
($num) = ($txtin =~ /This is line (.*)/);
print "linelen: $linelen, num: $num\n";
```

On some systems the result is:

```
linelen: 17, num: one
linelen: 17, num: two
```

On other systems (same perl version 5.10.1), the result is:

```
linelen: 18, num: one

linelen: 18, num: two
```

(Line length is one extra, and there's a carriage return included as part of the $num variable)

So in some systems input is picking up both the CR and LF, and the parse function is then picking up the CR as part of the wildcard assignment to $num, while in other systems the input is only picking up the CR, not the LF, and thus the parse function is not picking up the CR as part of the wildcard assignment to $num.  I have no idea why though.

Comment: This isn't a PERL unique issue. It's to do with the file end of line format. Most Linux boxes expects UNIX/OSX format, and it sounds like your file has EOL in Windows format, thus the CR and LF line breaks. Convert all your files EOL to UNIX/OSX format, and that should take care of it.

Comment: You say you get one result on "some systems" and the other result on "other systems". How are "some systems" and "other systems" different? Which linux distribution(s) and version(s) are running on each? Have you compared the output of `perl -V`? If it's all linux, then this definitely doesn't sound right...

Answer (score 1):

The :crlf PerlIO layer has two effects:

- When reading from a handle with :crlf, CRLF are translated to LF.
- When writing to a handle with :crlf, LF are translated to CRLF

On Windows builds, the :crlf PerlIO layer is automatically added to all file handles. The handle on the system where on which the line length was 17 had the :crlf layer, so the system must have been a Windows system.

On other systems, the :crlf PerlIO layer isn't used by default. The handle on the system on which the line length was 18 did not have the :crlf layer, so the system must have been a non-Windows system. (This includes Cygwin builds of Perls and other builds compiled in a unix-emulation environment.)

To force :crlf to not get added:

```
open(my $fh, '<:raw', $qfn) or die $!;
```

To force :crlf to not get added:

```
open(my $fh, '<', $qfn) or die $!;
binmode($fh);
```

To force :crlf to get added:

```
open(my $fh, '<:crlf', $qfn) or die $!;
binmode($fh);
```

If you're just reading, you could also handle both CRLF and LF. Instead of `chomp`, you could use the following:

```
s/\r?\n\z//;
```

The following is even better (since it gets rid of trailing other whitespace too):

```
s/\s+\z//;
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67171/discussion-on-answer-by-ikegami-perl-end-of-line-parse-discrepancy).